# Python: Memory error on google compute engine

Tags: python, linux, google-compute-engine

On google compute engine, I run the following:

```
z = np.zeros((10000, 32, 32, 3))
```

and get

> MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>   ----> 1 z = np.zeros((10000, 32, 32, 3))
>
> MemoryError: Unable to allocate 234. MiB for an array with shape
>   (10000, 32, 32, 3) and data type float64

This looks like the current OS configurations are preventing me from allocating large data chunks, which seems quite odd to me.

How can I get the memory I need to be allocated?

---

This is for [cs231n's assignment 2](http://cs231n.github.io/assignments2019/assignment2/), for loading CIFAR-10 to memory.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the array you are trying to create might be too large for the google computer engine. Think of it this way:

You are trying to allocate memory for a 4d array the size of 10000*32*32*3=30,720,000 cells, which is a lot! considering the standard size of flaot64 in python is 8, that's 245,760,000 bytes(245MB) worth of data to allocate with a single command!

you can allocate a byte array with similar size with the command:

```
z = bytearray(245760000)
```

but i dont exactly know what are you using this for so i can't tell if that will help you.

Even if there is a solution to allocate this amount of memory on google computer engine, I urge you to consider if you really need that much space. 
For instance, if you still need that big of an array but the values of each cell are either 0 or 1, you could make it a binary array, which will consist of 64 times less the space.

Again, reconsider if you really need that much space, and if you do need that big of an array than get more creative about how you store all that data.

Comment: Yes, I need it in memry, as it is the cifar-10 dataset. if it stays on disk, training would be extremely slow. Anyway, a reset of the machine solved it. no idea what caused this.